# Jquery validate plugin validation with thymeleaf not working

Tags: jquery, thymeleaf

Validation not working when I click submit button because of `th:field`, but if do not use it (`th:field`) validation working fine. So please help me out.

Html code

```
<input class="input-text full-width" type="text" th:name="houseNo" th:field="*{billingInfo.houseNo}" th:id="houseNo" placeholder="House No" />
```

jQuery code

```
$("#review").validate({

        rules: {
            houseNo: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            houseNo: $("#houseN").text()
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            alert("submit here");
            form.submit();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Link with java ? apparently no-one

Answer (score 1):

`th:field` overwrites the `name` and `value` properties of the `<input />` it is attached to.  (And additionally, it's will generate the `id` if it has not already been chosen.

w/`th:field`

Therefore, you need to change your javascript to match what `th:field` is doing.

```
<input class="input-text full-width" type="text" name="billingInfo.houseNo" id="houseNo" placeholder="House No" />
```

goes with

```
$("#review").validate({
    rules: {
        "billingInfo.houseNo": "required"
    },
    messages: {
        "billingInfo.houseNo": $("#houseN").text()
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        alert("submit here");
        form.submit();
    }
});
```